# refresh token vuejs some time next() provides error

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

it provides next is not function. how to fix it can anybody help in this
or is there any way this.$http can call recursively with same config until refresh token api does not return exception ?

```
 this.$http.interceptors.response.use(undefined, 
        function(err) => {
        return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {
          if(!err.response) {
            reject(err.response)
         }
        else{
        
            // Access Token was expired
            if (err.response.status === 401 && err.response.config && !err.response.config.__isRetryRequest) {
              
    
              try {
                const rs = await axiosInstance.post("/auth/refreshtoken", {
                  refreshToken: TokenService.getLocalRefreshToken(),
                });
    
                const { accessToken } = rs.data;
    
                store.dispatch('auth/refreshToken', accessToken);
                TokenService.updateLocalAccessToken(accessToken);
                //Have to call recursively if response doesn't came it says next is not a function how to fix it.
                next()
              } catch (_error) {
                logout();
                return Promise.reject(_error);
              }
            }
          }
    
          return Promise.reject(err);
        }
      );
    };
```

Comment: can you try return Promise.resolve(rs);